# Continuously print block of text if pattern matched

Tags: text, awk, sed

Input file has many repetitions of Blocks of text (demarcated with the keyword: "Blocks" at start and end). How would I print out only those blocks which do not contain "NoGrade" ? sed or awk would be preferable than pcgreg, perl (in which I can already create a solution.)
ADDITION TO QUESTION --> Also, how would one avoid duplicates from matched output ?
Input File (with duplicate block of text):

```
Blocks  
    GradeA  
    GradeZ  
    NoGrade  
Blocks  
    GradeA  
    GradeB   
    GradeC  
    GradeA  
Blocks  
    GradeD  
    GradeS  
    GradeE  
    NoGrade  
Blocks   
    GradeX  
    GradeY  
    GradeZ  
Blocks
    GradeA
    GradeB  
    GradeC  
    GradeA
Blocks
```

Output:

```
Blocks  
    GradeA  
    GradeB   
    GradeC  
    GradeA  
Blocks  
    GradeX  
    GradeY  
    GradeZ  
Blocks
```

Comment: Thank you A-Ray. That works and I understood the syntax. How can duplicate blocks be avoided in output though ? If I find this out, I'll post the answer here too.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -vRS='Blocks' '!/NoGrade/{printf "%s",$0 RT}' file
Blocks
GradeA
GradeB
GradeC
GradeA
Blocks
GradeX
GradeY
GradeZ
Blocks
```